# Exporting query to identify the exact points that fall into a polygon using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, spatial-join, query, arcgis-10.6

I am using ArcGIS 10.6.1. I have a shapefile consisting of points (facilities names and adresses). I also a shapefile consisting of polygons made up of enumeration areas as well as the Local Government Areas and States they fall into.

I want to find out how many points (that is the facilities) falls into each polygon as well as the exact points. I have tried this using the spatial join query. The points are 16,000 while the polygon are 687. The spatial join query is only giving me the number of points that fall into each polygon. But i also need to know the details of the point that fall into each polygon. Please how do I go about this?

Comment: You can use Select by location tool and get every point into new selection (and export it if you want).

Comment: I thought of that but I will have to do that 687 times. I was wondering if there is any other way out.

Comment: You can use Spatial Join with One-to-Many rule. It will give you every intersection of polygon and point with all point attributes. But number of polygons will be equally to number of points.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer attributes of the polygon within which it falls to each of your 16,000 points I would use the Intersect (Analysis) tool which:

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features. Features or
>   portions of features which overlap in all layers and/or feature
>   classes will be written to the output feature class.

Note that if you input point and polygon feature classes you will get points as output.

Comment: The intersect worked!!! The output attribute table had all the 16,000 points as well as the name of each polygon they fell into. Thanks alot!!!